# Is there software or a service to let you manage multiple crypto currency exchanges from one interface?

Tags: exchanges

There are so many cryptocurrency exchange sites (binance, bittrex, kucoin, poloniex, etc...) these days. Is there a software or service that taps into the API call of all these exchanges to be able to manage trades, deposits, and withdraws from one interface?

Answer (score 1):

check coinpayments API. supports trade(via shapeshift) deposits & withdraws with multiple currencies.

Comment: what does that have to do with managing multiple exchange accounts?

Comment: I answered your question. if this is not the answer you are looking for, please elaborate your "question" more clearly.

Comment: a second thought though. if you are looking for real-time-exchange(like trading) i think there is no open source code to play around for that matter. for example, Binance - a trading platform which uses THEIR OWN script to exchange from crypto to crypto.

Comment: updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

There are some apps for example [Tab Trader](https://tab-trader.com/) which allow you to trade on multiple exchanges by using their API keys. On computers, some trading bot applications be able to do should do similar things. However there's already a risk associated with using API keys and you should evaluate whether you want to use such software after all.